# How to read encrypted delta formatted s3 datasets using AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, delta-lake

I am wondering we have support for reading KMS-CSE encrypted delta formatted datasets through Athena?

I was going through https://docs.delta.io/0.5.0/presto-integration.htm which doesn't mention anything about encryption support.

If i have the manifest itself encrypted using KMS-CSE in s3, would I be able to read it successfully in Athena?

with the below command, I am able to create the table in athena.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `delta_athena_demo`(
  `id` bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://testing/_symlink_format_manifest/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='true')
```

however when I query, I am getting the following error:

> Your query has the following error(s):
>
> HIVE_UNKNOWN_ERROR: Detected encrypted objects. Please add TBLPROPERTIES (has_encrypted_data=true) to table properties.

---

(Found in delta-users@googlegroups.com)

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the AWS Athena support and they confirmed that Athena doesn't support reading from an encrypted symlink text input format manifest at the moment. They may consider this as a feature request in future.